# heroku postgresql odbc connection error

Tags: windows, heroku, odbc

I have installed the 64-bit ODBC client (PostgreSQL x64 9.01.02.00) on Windows 7 SP1 and configured a System DSN to my Heroku Postgres database (a dev database).

On testing, or trying to connect, I'm getting:

```
Connection Test Failed
SQL##f - SqlState: 28000, ErrorCode: 210, ErrorMsg: Communication closed during 
authentication;
Socket has been closed.
```

I've tried switching off the Windows firewall, but this doesn't resolve it.

Is there anything I need to run/configure in the Heroku database to allow ODBC connections?

I'd be grateful for any advice.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: When setting up the DSN I set SSL to 'REQUIRE'

Comment: Are you trying to connect from the command line? What authentication are you using?

Comment: @nathancahill, I'm trying to connect using 'test' when setting up a DSN in Windows, I've tried from an application as well with the same result. I'm using the database/username/password provided by Heroku with SSL required.

Comment: Can you connect with the same credentials and settings using `psql`?

Comment: @Craig Ringer, yes, I have pgAdminIII set up to connect to it with the same credentials in Ubuntu, although I haven't tested ODBC from Ubuntu (dual boot with Windows, where I'm experiencing the problem).

Comment: @d_a_n Well, testing under the most similar circumstances possible would be a good idea. Test under the same windows install you're testing with ODBC.

Comment: @CraigRinger, I've just installed postgres on Windows and connected successfully with psql using the same credentials. Is there anything I need to do to enable ODBC in Heroku, or any specific versions of ODBC to match database? Does it work on all database plans (this is the free dev plan). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @d_a_n Nope, the server-side doesn't care what client you're using, it doesn't tell (and often can't even tell) if it's psqlODBC, PgJDBC, plain libpq, or anything else. There's something different about how you're connecting with ODBC vs `psql`. Try enabling logging in psqlODBC and examining the psqlODBC logs; see if there's a more detailed error message in there.

Comment: @CraigRinger, I've enabled logging and it looks as though it establishes a connection but is getting "**** Error 10035 reading data from server"

Comment: @d_a_n Hmm, 10035 is winsock error `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`
- "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately". Could you be trying to use psqlODBC in an event-driven, non-blocking or asynchronous mode? (I don't use ODBC so I can't go into details on this part).

Answer (score -2):

Had a similar problem and I changed pg_hba.conf entry to method 'trust' instead of 'md5' and it solved my problem.

Comment: Be very careful with 'trust' as it will allow logins for any user with ANY password!

**From the doc:** "Trust: Allow the connection unconditionally. This method allows anyone that can connect to the PostgreSQL database server to login as any PostgreSQL user they wish, **without the need for a password or any other authentication**" from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: You can't change pg_hba.conf on heroku.